What radar sensors are supported by Matlab?
Looking for a radar sensor that can detect falls from 24ghz to 60ghz and can connect to matlab.
Help!
Also, I've been looking for an Infineon radar sensor at the moment, and I'm wondering if RDK, a self-developed tool, connects to matlab.
